# Remap SPI functions to default pins Arduino Zero via software?

Tags: spi, pins, arduino-zero

I am looking at the documentation for the Arduino Zero, and I am a little confused.

It indicates that pins 13, 12, and 11 can be used for CIPO, COPI and SCK, but using `SPI.begin()` puts the signals on the 6-pin header SPI pinout, which makes sense since it is designated for SPI.

Is there a way to switch to the digital pins via C code? Or do I need to edit the header files?  We are using another board that can only attach to the digital pins.

Comment: it looks like SERCOM1 could be configured as SPI on pins 11, 12, 13, but how do you want to use it?

Comment: I am sending a 32-bit word to another device via SPI protocol, and want to use all the same functions as the 6-pin header on the default digital pins.  I tried some pin mapping with the SERCOM but the code didn't seem to work.

Comment: the guide doesn't show how to use SERCOM for SPI, but similar approach as for Wire should work: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/communication/SamdSercom

Comment: guide for SPI by Adafruit https://learn.adafruit.com/using-atsamd21-sercom-to-add-more-spi-i2c-serial-ports/creating-a-new-spi

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Provably wrong answer below, see comments from though.

---

Unfortuantely the Arduino Zero doesn't support remapping of SPI pins as far as I know. Many other modern boards do, like the ESP8266/ESP32, but not the Zero, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's really unfortunate if that's the case. Why would they include the SPI options on the digital pins on the documentation?  Or is it just outdated? https://docs.arduino.cc/static/b1fbc77f1b73dcd9ac379af596e3472e/ABX00003-full-pinout.pdf

Comment: @eramirez2024 That it can't be remapped doesn't mean it has only one SERCOM, you can probably use another one. For example SERCOM0 is on pins PA04..PA07

Comment: @KIIV Apologies, I didn’t realize the Zero ran on the SAMD21, and I am not super knowledgeable about SERCOM, however I found this extremely relevant guide that may help (particularly pages 11-14) https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/using-atsamd21-sercom-to-add-more-spi-i2c-serial-ports.pdf